# PROC SQL MERGE MISMATCH

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

[ATTACHED SCREENSHOT OF DESIRED OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pvam.jpg)the required condition is
 "SUBJECT in A = SUBJECT in B 
and
VISIT in A NE(not equal to) VISIT in B"

I would like to find the exact mismatch and missing VISIT from the below Tables A and B by using Proc SQL procedure, Can anyone help me please?

Table A

```
SUBJECT Test    VISIT
1001    ABCB    1
1001    ABCD    2
1001    ABCD    3
1001    ABCD    5
```

Table B

```
SUBJECT Test    VISIT1
1001    ABCD    2
1001    ABCD    1
1001    ABCD    4
```

Expected output:

```
SUBJECT Test    VISIT   VISIT1
1001    ABCD    3
1001    ABCD    5    
1001    ABCD            4
```

VISIT 3 AND 5 IS PRESENT IN DATASET A NOT IN B AND VISIT 4 IS PRESENT IN DATASET2 NOT IN DATASET A , LIKE WISE
CODE FOR DATASET-

```
DATA A;
  LENGTH SUBJECT 8 Test $10 visit 8;
  INPUT SUBJECT Test $ visit ;
  DATALINES;
  1001 ABCD 1
  1001 ABCD 2
  1001 ABCD 3
  1001 ABCD 5
;
RUN;

DATA B;
  LENGTH SUBJECT 8 Test $10 visit1 8;
  INPUT SUBJECT Test $ visit1 ;
  DATALINES;
  1001 ABCD 2
  1001 ABCD 1
  1001 ABCD 4
;
RUN;
```

Thanks in advance!

the code i tried is below (but not working as expected)-

```
    ****************(VISIT ) in A and not in B****;
proc sql;
create table SS1 as
select distinct a.* FROM
A a where a.visit not in(select s.visit1 from B s WHERE A.SUBJECT = S.SUBJECT );

create  table   INRAVE as
select * from SS1 A
left join 
B B
on a.subject=b.SUBJECT  and a.VISIT NE b.VISIT1
where   b.SUBJECT is not  null  
;
quit;
****************VISIT in B and not in A****;
proc sql;
create table SS2 as
select distinct a.* from 
B a where a.VISIT1 not in(select S.VISIT from A s WHERE A.SUBJECT = S.SUBJECT );

create  table   INVENDOR as
select * from SS2 A
left join 
A B
on a.subject=b.SUBJECT  and a.VISIT1 NE b.VISIT 
where   b.SUBJECT is not  null  
;
quit;

data ALL;;
set inrave invendor;
where subject=subject ;
RUN;
```

Comment: So what SQL code did you try?

Comment: Hi Tom , I have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you know SQL very well, why not try `union all`, just like this:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table C as 
    select *, 'A' as Source from A
    where catx('@',SUBJECT,Test,visit) not in (
        select distinct catx('@',SUBJECT,Test,visit1) from B 
    )
    union all corr 
    select *, 'B' as Source from B(rename=VISIT1=VISIT)
    where catx('@',SUBJECT,Test,visit) not in (
        select distinct catx('@',SUBJECT,Test,visit) from A 
    )
    ;

    create table D(drop=TmpVISIT Source) as 
    select *,
        case when Source = 'B' then . else TmpVISIT end as VISIT,
        case when Source = 'B' then TmpVISIT else . end as VISIT1
    from C(rename=VISIT=TmpVISIT);
quit;
```

I get all obs from dataset A where not repeat in dataset B and do the oppsite with dataset B.
Well, I also get another solution, which is shorter:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select catx('@',SUBJECT,Test,visit) into :Ununique separated by '" "' from (
        select * from A union all select * from B(rename=visit1=visit)
    )
    group by SUBJECT, Test, visit
    having count(*) > 1;
quit;

data D;
    set A B;
    if catx('@',SUBJECT,Test,coalesce(visit1,visit)) in ("&Ununique") then delete;
run;
```

Whereas, this method is limited by the max lenth of macro variable.